# Subspace of a line in plane

Tags: general-topology

### If $L$ be a straight line in the plane, describe the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l\times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer: Let $L\equiv \alpha x+\beta y = \gamma$

Any basis element of $\mathbb{R}_l\times \mathbb{R}$ is $[a,b)\times (c,d)$
Then basis element of the subspace L inherits is $L \cap [a,b)\times (c,d)$

which are

$\{ x\times y : \alpha x+\beta y = \gamma , a\leq x < c \} $

or $\{ x\times y : \alpha x+\beta y = \gamma , \frac{\gamma - \beta c}{\alpha}< x < c \} $

or $\{ x\times y : \alpha x+\beta y = \gamma , a\leq x < \frac{\gamma - \beta d}{\alpha} \} $

or $\{ x\times y : \alpha x+\beta y = \gamma , \frac{\gamma - \beta c}{\alpha}< x < \frac{\gamma - \beta d}{\alpha} \} $

or $a\times \frac{\gamma - \beta a}{\alpha} \}$

or $\phi$

Is this all of it or there is something wrong (or may be what I did is actually wrong), help please.

Comment: You know, from drawing a picture, what $[a, b) \times (c, d)$ looks like. When you intersect it with a line, you get either an open interval in the line (by which I mean something of the form $q < x < r$) or a right-open interval (i.e., $q \le x < r$). Now the question is "are those two kinds of intervals open for every $q, r$", so you can give an answer like "the topology has a basis of all intervals of such-and-such a form". Hint: look carefully at the cases where $L$ is horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: $L$ is vertical. Parameterize $L$ via $t \mapsto P(t) = (u, t)$. We'll describe a basis for the topology of $L$ in terms of $t$-intervals.

The intersection of $L$ with $[a, b) \times (c, d)$ is empty unless $a \le u < b$, so the empty set is in our basis.

If $a \le u < b$, then the intersection consists of all points $P(t)$ with 
$$
c <  t < d,
$$
so the $t$-interval $(c, d)$ is in the basis.

Conclusion: the basis consists of the empty set and all intervals $(c, d)$ for $c, d, \in \Bbb R$. In other words: a vertical line inherits the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Case 2: $L$ is horizontal. [you fill in the rest here]

Case 3: $L$ is diagonal, consisting of points $(x, y)$ satisfying $Ax + By + C = 0$ where $B \ne 0$. In this case, rewrite $L$ as points $(x, y)$ satisfying
$$
y = \frac{A}{B} x - \frac{C}{B}
$$
We can then paramterize this line via
$$
t \mapsto P(t) = (t, -\frac{A}{B}t - \frac{C}{B}).
$$

The intersection of the line with the rectangle $[a ,b) \times (c, d)$ may be empty or one of two other possibilities.

1. If $L$ meets the left edge of the rectangle, the intersection is a "half-open interval in $t$" (i.e., a set of points $P(t)$ each of which satisfies $u \le t < v$).
2. If $L$ does not meet the left edge of the rectangle, the intersection is ... [you fill in here]